# Start with core data in project?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I will start developing a new project for iOS. I am unsure for now if I should use core data in this project, or not. I will find out along the way, while developing (most likely with some coaching help).

Now my noob question is: Should I, while creating my new project, already check the option 'use core data'? Or shouldnt I?

Basically my question is: What is more difficult, removing core data when I checked the option and I will not been using it after all? Or adding core data when I did not check the option and I will be using it after all?

I have found it is not super difficult to add after:[Implement CoreData into an existing project using Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25675389/implement-coredata-into-an-existing-project-using-swift)
But still, it seems like alot of hassle, so I now ask u!
Thanks for the answer in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't matter. Starting with Core Data just prepares the core data code in the app delegate and makes an empty model file, both of which are

1) easy to create yourself, or

2) copy from a new empty project started with core data later when you need it.

And if you already have it in your project, but you don't use it, it is also no problem. I found that almost all projects need core data after a while, so I usually just let it create it from the start.

Answer (score 3):

Xcode just allows you to check using coredata to prepare already a coredata for you project.

BUt it is very simple to add or remove it later.JUst simple as File>create or File delete.

In a words don't worry about creating in the begining or later.